# How to get line number from an XmlElement or a XPathNavigator

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I try to get the line number from an XmlNode (which is an XmlElement) but it cannot be cast as an IXmlLineInfo. So I tried with XPathNavigator but it doesn't work either.

How can I get its line number?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a typo in your cast, like missing parentheses. Yet it's just speculation without code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works fine for me with XPathNavigator over an XPathDocument, the snippet

```
    XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("XMLFile1.xml");
    foreach (XPathNavigator element in doc.CreateNavigator().Select("//*"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Element {0} at line {1}.", element.Name, (IXmlLineInfo)element != null ? ((IXmlLineInfo)element).LineNumber : 0);
    }
```

for the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <foo>3</foo>
  <foo>4</foo>
</root>
```

outputs

```
Element root at line 2.
Element foo at line 3.
Element foo at line 4.
```

I think for XmlDocument you would need to extend the DOM implementation. If you want to manipulate an XML document then these days in the .NET world I would use XDocument/XElement, there you can set load options to ensure you get an IXmlLineInfo, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538371%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.loadoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Can't test but yeah, looks fine to me.

Comment: I don't know why it don't work for me but I changed the way I read the document to use XDocument instead of XmlDocument and it works fine !
Thanks !

Comment: In my case the xml was in-memory from an up-stream pull, and all XML was on line 1. For this scenario, use `.LinePosition` instead - works great.